# adding xml node after last child for repetitive node

Tags: xslt

I need to add a node after the last child node of a repetitive node
I have an XML with node Parameter that is ripetitive
I need to add a node after the last node of Parameter

This is my file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SyncPulseTask releaseID="10.1.3" xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
<ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
        <LogicalID>infor.engine.pulse</LogicalID>
        <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2014-09-29T15:47:05.080Z</CreationDateTime>
</ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
    <Sync>
        <TenantID>infor</TenantID>
        <ActionCriteria>
            <ActionExpression actionCode="Add"/>
        </ActionCriteria>
    </Sync>
    <PulseTask>
        <DocumentID>
            <ID variationID="1">756</ID>
        </DocumentID>
        <CreationDateTime>2014-09-29T15:47:04Z</CreationDateTime>
        <LastModificationDateTime>2014-09-29T15:47:05Z</LastModificationDateTime>
        <Status>
            <Code>NEW</Code>
        </Status>
        <EscalationLevel>0</EscalationLevel>
        <Priority>MEDIUM</Priority>
        <Description>Generate Pulse BOD</Description>
        <Source>
            <Type>WORKFLOW</Type>
            <Name>LN_DA_ProjectContractLine</Name>
            <Version>46.0</Version>
        </Source>
        <Parameter sequence="1">
            <Name>Contract</Name>
            <Value>CON000089</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Contract</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="2">
            <Name>ContractAmount</Name>
            <Value>1.0</Value>
            <DataType>DECIMAL</DataType>
            <Label>Contract Amount</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="3">
            <Name>ContractCurrency</Name>
            <Value>GBP</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Contract Currency</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="4">
            <Name>ContractLine</Name>
            <Value>0030</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Contract Line</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="5">
            <Name>ContractManager</Name>
            <Value>RDKORTE</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Contract Manager</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="6">
            <Name>ContractManagerName</Name>
            <Value>Ron de Korte</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Contract Manager Name</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="7">
            <Name>ExternalSalesRepName</Name>
            <Value>Jan Slag</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>External Sales Rep Name</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="8">
            <Name>ExternalSalesRepresentative</Name>
            <Value>JSLAG</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>External Sales Representative</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="9">
            <Name>InternalSalesRepName</Name>
            <Value>James Rea</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Internal Sales Rep Name</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="10">
            <Name>InternalSalesRepresentative</Name>
            <Value>JREA</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Internal Sales Representative</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="11">
            <Name>LogicalId</Name>
            <Value>lid://infor.ln.infor_ln_10_3_1_company_512</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Logical Id</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="12">
            <Name>SalesOffice</Name>
            <Value>SBASUK</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Sales Office</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="13">
            <Name>SoldToBPName</Name>
            <Value>BAES CS&amp;S</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Sold To BPName</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="14">
            <Name>SoldToBusinessPartner</Name>
            <Value>K0999</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Sold To Business Partner</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="15">
            <Name>SoldToContact</Name>
            <Value/>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Sold To Contact</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="16">
            <Name>SoldToContactName</Name>
            <Value/>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Sold To Contact Name</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="17">
            <Name>Status</Name>
            <Value>20</Value>
            <DataType>INTEGER</DataType>
            <Label>Status</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="18">
            <Name>StatusBeforeOnHold</Name>
            <Value/>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Status Before On Hold</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="19">
            <Name>StatusOld</Name>
            <Value>0</Value>
            <DataType>INTEGER</DataType>
            <Label>Status Old</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="20">
            <Name>StatusOldName</Name>
            <Value/>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Status Old Name</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="21">
            <Name>StatusPreviousOld</Name>
            <Value>0</Value>
            <DataType>INTEGER</DataType>
            <Label>Status Previous Old</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="22">
            <Name>SubmitUser</Name>
            <Value>infor20</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Submit User</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="23">
            <Name>TaskUser</Name>
            <Value/>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Task User</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="24">
            <Name>WF_Reason</Name>
            <Value/>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>WF Reason</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>false</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <DistributionPerson>
            <ID>768</ID>
            <PersonReference>
                <IDs>
                    <ID>mike.tollan@sharelnk30.net</ID>
                </IDs>
                <Name>Mike Tollan</Name>
                <SystemUserIndicator>true</SystemUserIndicator>
            </PersonReference>
        </DistributionPerson>
    </PulseTask>
</DataArea>
</SyncPulseTask>`
```

and this is what i would have

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SyncPulseTask releaseID="10.1.3" xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
<ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
        <LogicalID>infor.engine.pulse</LogicalID>
        <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2014-09-29T15:47:05.080Z</CreationDateTime>
</ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
    <Sync>
        <TenantID>infor</TenantID>
        <ActionCriteria>
            <ActionExpression actionCode="Add"/>
        </ActionCriteria>
    </Sync>
    <PulseTask>
        <DocumentID>
            <ID variationID="1">756</ID>
        </DocumentID>
        <CreationDateTime>2014-09-29T15:47:04Z</CreationDateTime>
        <LastModificationDateTime>2014-09-29T15:47:05Z</LastModificationDateTime>
        <Status>
            <Code>NEW</Code>
        </Status>
        <EscalationLevel>0</EscalationLevel>
        <Priority>MEDIUM</Priority>
        <Description>Generate Pulse BOD</Description>
        <Source>
            <Type>WORKFLOW</Type>
            <Name>LN_DA_ProjectContractLine</Name>
            <Version>46.0</Version>
        </Source>
        <Parameter sequence="1">
            <Name>Contract</Name>
            <Value>CON000089</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Contract</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="2">
            <Name>ContractAmount</Name>
            <Value>1.0</Value>
            <DataType>DECIMAL</DataType>
            <Label>Contract Amount</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="3">
            <Name>ContractCurrency</Name>
            <Value>GBP</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Contract Currency</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="4">
            <Name>ContractLine</Name>
            <Value>0030</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Contract Line</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="5">
            <Name>ContractManager</Name>
            <Value>RDKORTE</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Contract Manager</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="6">
            <Name>ContractManagerName</Name>
            <Value>Ron de Korte</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Contract Manager Name</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="7">
            <Name>ExternalSalesRepName</Name>
            <Value>Jan Slag</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>External Sales Rep Name</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="8">
            <Name>ExternalSalesRepresentative</Name>
            <Value>JSLAG</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>External Sales Representative</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="9">
            <Name>InternalSalesRepName</Name>
            <Value>James Rea</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Internal Sales Rep Name</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="10">
            <Name>InternalSalesRepresentative</Name>
            <Value>JREA</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Internal Sales Representative</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="11">
            <Name>LogicalId</Name>
            <Value>lid://infor.ln.infor_ln_10_3_1_company_512</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Logical Id</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="12">
            <Name>SalesOffice</Name>
            <Value>SBASUK</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Sales Office</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="13">
            <Name>SoldToBPName</Name>
            <Value>BAES CS&amp;S</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Sold To BPName</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="14">
            <Name>SoldToBusinessPartner</Name>
            <Value>K0999</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Sold To Business Partner</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="15">
            <Name>SoldToContact</Name>
            <Value/>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Sold To Contact</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="16">
            <Name>SoldToContactName</Name>
            <Value/>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Sold To Contact Name</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="17">
            <Name>Status</Name>
            <Value>20</Value>
            <DataType>INTEGER</DataType>
            <Label>Status</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="18">
            <Name>StatusBeforeOnHold</Name>
            <Value/>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Status Before On Hold</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="19">
            <Name>StatusOld</Name>
            <Value>0</Value>
            <DataType>INTEGER</DataType>
            <Label>Status Old</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="20">
            <Name>StatusOldName</Name>
            <Value/>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Status Old Name</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="21">
            <Name>StatusPreviousOld</Name>
            <Value>0</Value>
            <DataType>INTEGER</DataType>
            <Label>Status Previous Old</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="22">
            <Name>SubmitUser</Name>
            <Value>infor20</Value>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Submit User</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="23">
            <Name>TaskUser</Name>
            <Value/>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>Task User</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>true</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter sequence="24">
            <Name>WF_Reason</Name>
            <Value/>
            <DataType>STRING</DataType>
            <Label>WF Reason</Label>
            <ReadOnlyIndicator>false</ReadOnlyIndicator>
        </Parameter>
        <AssignedPerson>
            <PersonReference>
                <IDs>
                    <ID>mike.tollan@sharelnk30.net</ID>
                </IDs>
            </PersonReference>
        </AssignedPerson>           
        <DistributionPerson>
            <ID>768</ID>
            <PersonReference>
                <IDs>
                    <ID>mike.tollan@sharelnk30.net</ID>
                </IDs>
                <Name>Mike Tollan</Name>
                <SystemUserIndicator>true</SystemUserIndicator>
            </PersonReference>
        </DistributionPerson>
    </PulseTask>
</DataArea>
</SyncPulseTask>`
```

basically i need to add the AssignedPerson node
how can i do that?

thank you

Comment: I am sure you can size this down a bit (in the spirit of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Also, please include your current XSLT code.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
xmlns:a="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
exclude-result-prefixes="a">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:Parameter[not(following-sibling::a:Parameter)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <AssignedPerson>
        <PersonReference>
            <IDs>
                <ID>mike.tollan@sharelnk30.net</ID>
            </IDs>
        </PersonReference>
    </AssignedPerson>         
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a default namespace, you should prefix this, say "test" and use this prefix later in xpath

```
xmlns:test="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
```

First, you need an identity template

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, override the `DistributionPerson` node to include the node that you want:

```
<xsl:template match="test:DistributionPerson">
    <AssignedPerson>
        <PersonReference>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="test:PersonReference/test:IDs"/>
        </PersonReference>
    </AssignedPerson>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:test="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
    exclude-result-prefixes="test">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="test:DistributionPerson">
        <AssignedPerson>
            <PersonReference>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="test:PersonReference/test:IDs"/>
            </PersonReference>
        </AssignedPerson>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You could also add the namespace for a second time in your XSLT as default. That way you do not need to have the namespace attribute in XSL element.

Comment: Hi, i don't need to overwrite, i need to add the AssignedPerson node between the last Parameter node and DistributionPerson node

Comment: @MarkVeenstra, good point. I am editing my answer now. zanza67, I meant override.

Comment: @zanza67 Please clarify: will there **always** be `DistributionPerson` after the last `Parameter`?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you find this answer useful, please tick the check mark below the arrowheads at the left to make it appear green. This way, other users can know that this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:agis="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" exclude-result-prefixes="agis">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="agis:Parameter[last()]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
        <AssignedPerson>
            <PersonReference>
                <IDs>
                    <ID><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::agis:DistributionPerson/agis:PersonReference/agis:IDs/agis:ID" /></ID>
                </IDs>
            </PersonReference>
        </AssignedPerson> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note that this `[last()]` will not work with libxslt.